# Difference betweene datatype XML and HTML

Tags: ajax, xml, parse-error

What is the difference between

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "logs/old-vs-new.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) { ...
```

And

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "logs/old-vs-new.xml",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(xml) { ...
```

I know the dataType is different. But when I use datatype xml I get the parsererror and with datatype html it works fine. It's strange because my file I want to work with is a XML file. 
My XML file consist now out of more than 5000 lines, but when a decrement it to about 800 lines it works too with datatype XML.

Someone an idea?

Comment: `dataType` tells jQuery what format will be the returned result and this way it will know how to parse it... your returned result is xml or html?

Comment: Some where after the 800th line, you have markup that's non-compliant as far as the xml processor you are using is concerned.

Comment: @florin.prisecariu My returned data is XML.

Comment: add your xml response into a xml validator like http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ ... i assume it is broken xml and jQuery fails to parse it

Comment: @TonyHopkinson

I validated my xml code and indeed, the problem was in my xml. I used special chars between my tags and that was my fault. Now i edited my code and replaced the special chars with html entities.

Comment: Aye well, I'd like to claim it's an issue I'd ever seen before, but that would make me a damn liar. :(

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved.

My markup wasn't right.

I used special chars between my tags and that was my fault. Now i edited my code and replaced the special chars with html entities.

So peoples with the same problem as me, first try to validate your xml code with a validator which you can find on the web.

Thanks Tony Hopkinson and florin.prisecariu!